# Add new wordlist.txt to the SAPI dictionary programmically

Tags: delphi, sapi

I'm developing a new Delphi app which uses the voice to text dictation as its main data input, the required data is specifically related to medical terms, for example the user is needed to enter any or all of those words only (hypertension , stroke , heart disease , kidney disease , ...etc).
As I have very limited knowleage with COM objects programming so I was searching for an easy solution to train the sapi 5.4 about those medical terms which may be hundrends in number by making a text wordlist and programmically introduce this list to the sapi voice recognition engine. I want it to be done via code and not to be via sapi training window or wizard.
I try the following : By copy the whole wordlist.txt (about 100,000 word) into a TFDTable named (WordList) then I run this code, But It Fail to run with out any error message.

```
 Procedure TForm1.BtnClick( Sender : TObject );
Var
  Hr : HRESULT;
Begin
  Wordlist.First;
  While Not Wordlist.Eof Do
    Begin
      SpLexicon.AddPronunciation( Wordlist.FieldByName( 'Field1' )
          .AsString ,
        406 , SPPS_Noun , '' );
      If Hr = S_OK Then
        Wordlist.Next
      Else
        Begin
          ShowMessage( 'Failed' );
          Exit
        End;
    End;
  ShowMessage( 'OK' );
End;
```

What is the wrong I have done?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29583 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1021537/4299358 is still online - at which part are you failing and what's your code so far?

Comment: Dear AmigoJack, I know how to add single word at a time via AddPronunciation method but I just can not find how to add a text file of many words programmically?

Comment: If I understand you, adding a single word works. Right? By the way, why load the text file into a TFDTable instead of directly calling SAPI functions as you read the text file?

Comment: Your code lacks the declaration of all variable. How would you that we check your code? Please provide a complete, simple program reproducing the issue you have. At least I see that your check Hr for success but you don't assign it!

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to "how to read a text file line by line" easily. Whatever type `SpLexicon` is: there's no need it can deal with reading files - that's a basic task unbound to any context.

Comment: From a speech perspective, adding 100,000 words to the user lexicon is a _bad_ idea.   You want a custom language model, not the mother of all lexicons.